# MongoDB with atomic FindAndDelete operations as a poor man's queue replacement?

Tags: mongodb, performance, queue, atomic

Using FindAndDelete would imply that we read only one message per request from concurrent consumers.
We will have a max of 100-150 reads/second. We have a fairly large Mongo Atlas cluster.
The question is how will this approach affect the overall performance of our cluster? At what numbers should we expect performance degradation?